# Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
org 100h 

.MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 200 
.DATA 
crlf DB 0dh,0ah,"$" 
prompt1 DB "Enter celcius:","$" 
prompt2 DB "In Fahrenheit:","$" 
prompt3 DB ".","$" 
result DB ? 
c DB ? 
x1 Dw ? 
y DW 8 
x DW 1 
z dw 10 

.code 
.startup 

lea dx,prompt1 
mov ah,09h 
int 21h 

mov ah,01h 
int 21h 

sub al,30h 
mov c,al 

lea dx,crlf 
mov ah,09h 
int 21h 

mov al,c 
mul x 
mov x1,ax 
mov al,c 
mul y 
idiv z 
add al,c 
add al,32 
mov result,al 

lea dx,prompt2 
mov ah,09h 
int 21h 

mov dl,result 
add ah,02h 
int 21h 

.exit 
end
```

But it only its only accepting 1 char I need it at least 4 char and this code does not show the result.

Comment: I strongly advise you to comment the different parts of your code. It is very important in general, but it is vital with assembly.

Answer (score 1):

The DOS function 1 (int 21h) inputs only a single character from keyboard. You need the function 0Ah, which is buffered input.

```
Buffered Keyboard Input
AH = 0Ah
DS:DX = pointer to input buffer of the format:

max count BUFFER (N bytes)
   count = number of characters returned (byte)
   max =  maximum number of characters to read (byte)

returns nothing

- N bytes of data are read from STDIN into buffer+2
```

Comment: sorry but i get comfused so what do i have to do to run this programm?

Comment: Instead using function 01h (`mov ah,01h; int 21h`) which reads a single character from keyboard (that's your main issue,isn't it) you can use function 0Ah (`mov ah,0ah`) and setup pointer to the buffer into `DS:DX`) in order to read *multiple* characters from keyboard. After a user inputs characters using his/her keyboard the inputed characters are stored in memory starting from location (DS:DX)+2. The number of inputed characters is at location DS:DX. So you have the string that the user typed in. Then you have to translate this string into a number (representing temperature in celsius).